# iOS Use Current Location Permission dialog is shown twice in Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, geolocation

I have a `Phonegap` app. I am including `cordova.js` in the HTML (but not in the `www` directory), I am waiting for `deviceready` to be fired, and then I'm calling

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,failCallback);
```

I'm receiving both versions of the dialog (in this order):

Native Dialog - https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5y1O.png 
HTML Dialog - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbcmR.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using version 3+ of PhoneGap, make sure you're correctly including the plugin.

From the [PhoneGap v3.0.0 API Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation_accessing_the_feature) :

> As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-line Interface, to add or remove this feature for a project

Comment: AH! this is perfect. I can't believe I missed this.

Comment: @brandonjp If you have missed the installation of the plugin then how could the two messages appear for you? I have installed the plugin as it was discribed in the documentation and I still have both of the mentioned messages. Any Idea?

Comment: Hello, How to Disable Location permission alert on iPhone with Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that's because there was not successfully installed phonegap geolocation plugin. Do you know how install it? Please check how to on http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Answer (score 0):

Do not call getCurrentPosition immediately after deviceready has been fired. geolocation plugin is not ready, so navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition actually calls HTML5 api, then you see the HTML dialog. I do below to make sure geolocation plugin is ready before calling navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in my ionic project.

```
    var my_getposition = function() {
        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() && !window.Coordinates) {
            $timeout(function(){ my_getposition(); }, 500);
            return;
        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to run "cordova prepare" in order to change the config.xml and it will automatically generate cordova_plugins.js that will be used for the geolocation plugin.

Just beware because when you do run cordova prepare it will erase all your /www folder.

Tipically you would have to add all the plugins and set up your environment before you add your code to the /www folder...