# Change Display Name of Cordova Geolocation iOS

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I want to change the display name of the ios location popup: „Would like to use your current location“. Does somebody has any idea?

[image]

Comment: It should show the name of your app when it's released.

Comment: I've already upload it to TestFlight but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Post Location permission alert - [Location permission alert on iPhone with Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302242/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-cordova/30742445#30742445)

Use this plugin for Alert - **`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`**

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'Alert Message',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Alert Title',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

[Read More](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/)