# Cordova geolocation plugin failing to display location message

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Failing to get the [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/) 4.0.1 to work in an iOS app, despite following all instructions. When the app asks for location permission, the geolocation message displays the path of the webview:

> /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../www/index.html

rather than the name of the app and the message in the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` string.

I have tried solutions in other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810880/cordova-ios-location-message), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891339/fix-cordova-geolocation-ask-for-location-message), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302242/location-permission-alert-on-iphone-with-cordova)):

- The location is not requested until well after the device is ready --- this happens only when the user goes to a particular page in the app.
- I have removed and added the plugin *many* times. All plugin files seem to be where they should be.
- The `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is properly set in `config.xml` and `info.plist`. And just to be safe, the variable `GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION` is also set in `config.xml`.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we had overlooked a solution that has already been suggested ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883250/4675003) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891337/4675003)) by others. Namely, `cordova.js` must be included in `index.html`. This is not documented in the Cordova geolocation plugin.