# How to change "http://localhost:8080" to the name of the app for cordova ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

I just pushed my app to Testflight and we having the issue with this - (https://snipboard.io/u6eqLa.jpg).

How can I change the "http://localhost:8080" to my app name?

I did install geolocation plugin by `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION=“my_project would like to use your location"` and Then manually edit the platform/ios/{project}/{project}/project.info.plist file and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add your description for requiring permission here</string>
```

I did a lot of research and tried a lot of ways on Stackoverflow but didnt help at all. Can anyone have ideas to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova iOS location message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810880/cordova-ios-location-message)

Comment: @Eric what does it mean to wait for the device ready online? I test it on the ios simulator. it should be online for the app to display. Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: @Eric I still get the same error. I pushed the app to TestFlight but it still saying "localhost would like to use your location". How can I change localhost to my app name? Thanks!